# What is the lowest energy solution for emptying a drip irrigation water collector : a mono-stable solenoid valve or a bistable coupled to a pump?

Tags: pumps, energy-efficiency, valves, water-resources

I have a water collector I want to empty everyday for drip irrigation. It is controlled by a micro-controller. I have identified three solutions:

1. Use a bi-stable electro-valve and a pump: advantage is I can let the valve open hours with no electricity consumption, drawback is products I have found require a minimal working pressure of 0.2 bar, which is equivalent to a 2 meters water column I can difficutly have, then I would need to add a pump with its own power consumption during all the watering
2. Use a mono-stable electrovalve : advantages are it is the simpliest solution, as no minimal working pressure is required, I don't need to add a pump, drawback is the valve needs power to remain open
3. Use a bi-stable electro-valve, a pump and an additional tank: to mitigate solution 1, I can add a 20 liters tank at 2.5 meters high to get 0.25 bar at the valve thanks to the created water column. The pump fills the small ceiling tank from the main one each time a low level sensor triggers, and until a high level sensor triggers. Say the main tank is 100l, I would have to refill 6 times (margins). Advantage : less energy, the pump is used far less than in solution 1, drawback : more complex and more equipments

Is there a better solution than the 3rd one, possibly with no power during all the watering time?

Comment: I'd keep looking for a better bistable valve

Comment: Do you have some references to share?

Comment: I am looking at motorized relays, but opening/closing time is between 10s and 20s

Comment: This was posted on Electrical Engineering earlier.

Comment: I thought it was the wrong stack, so I deleted it a posted here. Am I right?

Comment: try looking thru these (didn't check in detail). https://m.alibaba.com/showroom/bistable-valve.html   ... typ 2-wire, positive pulse opens, negative pulse closes. drive with H bridge... use search terms "bistable irrigation valve"

Comment: if you take apart some of the older cheapo programmable watering timers they have a geared (~3V) toy motor cranking a valve! no reason you couldn't do the same.

Comment: I have ordered motorized bistable valves, they don't have minimal working pressure. I will setup the answer when actually tested